# Specifying site directory outside of the script

Tags: python

Is it possible to specify site directories through python command line or environment?
Right now I'm using `site.addsitedir`, but I would like to make the script agnostic of the site-setting logic

Answer (score 0):

The PYTHONPATH environment variable is essentially the same thing. Set it to a directory containing Python modules or packages and it will be added to sys.path at initialization.